# x64 to x86 conversion problem with Detours

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86, x86-64, detours

I want to use the repo [detours.net](https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net) in my project to hook native win32 api functions. It is working create for x64 applications but not for x86 applications. So I have changed to CMakeList.txt in the detours directory to `-E env DETOURS_TARGET_PROCESSOR=X86` and creating the Visual Studio Project File with this command: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32  ..\detours.net`. After trying to build the solution i get an error in this line:

```
return DetourEnumerateImportsEx(hModule, &context, nullptr, Unsandbox);
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'BOOL DetourEnumerateImportsEx(HMODULE,PVOID,PF_DETOUR_IMPORT_FILE_CALLBACK,PF_DETOUR_IMPORT_FUNC_CALLBACK_EX)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'BOOL (__cdecl *)(PVOID,DWORD,LPCSTR,PVOID *)' to 'PF_DETOUR_IMPORT_FUNC_CALLBACK_EX'   DetoursDll  C:\Users\sebastian\source\repos\de32\detours.net\detours.net\DetoursDll\src\DetoursDll.cpp  30
```

But the definition of PF_DETOUR_IMPORT_FILE_CALLBACK to the function 'Unsandbox' seems correct:

```
typedef BOOL (CALLBACK *PF_DETOUR_IMPORT_FUNC_CALLBACK_EX)(_In_opt_ PVOID pContext,
                                                           _In_ DWORD nOrdinal,
                                                           _In_opt_ LPCSTR pszFunc,
                                                           _In_opt_ PVOID* ppvFunc);
```

```
static BOOL Unsandbox(_In_opt_ PVOID pContext, _In_ DWORD nOrdinal, _In_opt_ LPCSTR pszFunc, _In_opt_ PVOID* ppvFunc)
```

It's building without any problems for x64 but not for x86. Did I miss anything?

Comment: `CALLBACK` is probably the calling convention and is missing on the definition.  It's probably a null macro in x64 but has a value in x86.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am new to c++ and only want to use the library in my .net project. Can you please explain a little bit more in detail?

Comment: In your code change `static BOOL Unsandbox(...` to `static BOOL CALLBACK Unsandbox(...`  Further reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/calling-conventions?view=msvc-160